# Wordpress - Plugin to differentiate post content by user role

Tags: php, wordpress

My client wants to have a Wordpress site with two separate types of users in mind. For each of these personas, different post content will be displayed to the user.

Currently, I'm using [Query Wrangler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-wrangler/) to separate content. However, as far as I can tell, it does not have the ability to default to one persona and keep it throughout the site. It's essentially two separate sites I'm building, but with some shared content, which is what's making this difficult.

Are there any plugins or workarounds I can use to get the functionality I need?

Answer (score 1):

I use custom templates along with this plugin to control what types of content my WP users see . http://themehybrid.com/plugins/members It allows you to create custom roles and check against those roles at anytime.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing that out currently. The one issue I'm thinking I might run into - the users won't be logging in or have assigned roles. The user just selects which role fits them and the site content changes. Is this possible with this plugin?